# Weird singleton initialization in static function initialize during unit tests

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, singleton, static-initializer

I have a following code in my singleton class

```
static MySingleton *gManager;
+(void)initialize
{
   if(self == [MySingleton class])
   {
       gManager = [[MySingleton alloc] initWithServices:[[MyServices alloc] init]];
   }
}
+(MySingleton *)sharedInstance
{
   return (gManager);
}
```

Unfortunately, during the unit tests I see that gManager is an instance of type SenTestCaseRun. I cant seem to figure out why?
So a call like 
[[MySingleton sharedInstance] myFunction];

results in an error that myFunction is an unknown selector although it exists in the MySingleton class.

It is of type SenTestCaseRun because I checked using NSStringFromClass function.

Any pointers? Already banged my head for 3-4 hours on this :(.

Comment: I don't know what language this is, but doesn't actually look like `C`

Comment: I think the OP typed `objective c` into the tags box. Fixed it.

Comment: Its is objective C. I added that in my tags. How can I make it more clear?

Comment: @user628921: like larsmans corrected: `objective-c`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a breakpoint in `+initialize` to make sure this variable is set correctly. If that doesn't explain it, use a [watchpoint](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeDebugging/200-Managing_Program_Execution/program_execution.html) on it to see who's modifying it.

Comment: I tried it under the debugger and the only place the global gManager gets initialized is during the unit test startup with following call stack ` #0in +[AudioManager initialize] at AudioManager.m:118
#1in _class_initialize
#2in _class_initialize
#3in prepareForMethodLookup
#4in lookUpMethod
#5in _class_lookupMethodAndLoadCache
#6in objc_msgSend
#7in +[NSObject(SenTestRuntimeUtilities) senAllSubclasses]
#8in +[SenTestSuite updateCache]
#9in +[SenTestSuite suiteForBundleCache]
#10in +[SenTestSuite testSuiteForBundlePath:]
#11in +[SenTestProbe specifiedTestSuite]
#12in +[SenTestProbe runTests:]`

Comment: That's from the watchpoint? And it's assigned to the correct class at that point, but later crashes because it's the wrong class?

Comment: Ok found out the problem. I was releasing my singleton during the app shutdown [[MySingleton sharedInstance] release]. If referenced later the global was a random instance set by the runtime. It does not makes sense to release a singleton but then I needed to release some resources. So I refactored the code. BTW, my code worked well on the device but unit tests were invoking app shutdown events many times.

Comment: Glad it worked out. Remember that -dealloc never guaranteed to run, and is generally skipped during application quit, so if you have external resources you need to release, you have to observe `NSApplicationWillTerminate`, or arrange to be called by someone who does.

Answer (score 1):

it may be better to just put the initialization code inside the shared instance method

```
+(MySingleton *)shared
{
    static MySingleton *sharedInstance = nil;
    if(sharedInstance == nil){
        sharedInstance = [[MySingleton alloc] init];
    }
    return sharedInstance;
}
```

also in your code you are comparing an object to a class which will never be true instead of comparing [self class] to [MySingleton class].

Comment: The advantage of the OP's version is that it is threadsafe. In a class method like `+initialize`, `self` is the class.